# fluid layout, differences for content vs padding and margins

Tags: responsive-design, fluid-layout

So I'm just trying to grasp this concept. In the image bellow you can see that the total width of the sub elements is 250px, and they are both surrounded by 10 px of padding..So to get the percentage we need to do target/context. The part I don't understand is that to get the percentage of the total width(250px) we calculate that based on the parent's total width(590px), but to calculate the percentage of the padding(10px), we do so based on the parent's inner width (570px).. So why is that? or more specifically why isn't the 250px percentage calculated off the 570px also, as it would seem the 570px div's padding has no barring on the space taken up by the 250px block. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that diagram a bit confusing and it's hard to answer your question using it alone, I hope **[this example I've mocked up](http://wturrell.co.uk/stackoverflow/20130719-01.html)** will help (usually easier to look at live code) - be sure to read the source and examine the size of the individual elements using Chrome Developer Tools (the Metrics section and simply hovering over the individual `<div>`s with the Elements tab open) or your browser's equivalent.

In the diagram, they've used percentages but have confused things by rounding them; never round percentages up/down when doing responsive design, just use the exact figure (or if you're drawing a diagram, show the target and context calculation), browsers (with some ancient exceptions) can always cope with multiple decimal places. (Ideally you'd use a CSS pre-processor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) which will do the maths for you).

Also, I've simplified things by just having two columns and floating them left/right, I think the third central 20px column in the drawing makes it harder to understand.  Get it working with equal left/right padding for everything first then worry about the more complex stuff, only use a third div if you actually need something inside it.

You also need to be aware of the [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) - the sub elements width is 250px, but if have a 250px wide box and use CSS to add 10px padding either size, the display width will be 270px because it's the width (or height), plus any border, plus padding.  This can get really confusing - what you actually want is something that's still 250px wide with 10px left/right padding within it - often it's easier to turn this behaviour off - as in my example - with `box-sizing: border-box;` (there's a Mozilla prefix needed).

You **always** use the parent (the element's container) for the context when setting flexible margins **or** padding.  You may note that I've used 570 rather than 590 in the calculation for `.rectangle` because 570px is the effective width you have to work with for Column 1, the 20px is just padding on either side, I'm still looking at the parent element though, nothing else.  The rectangles also have left/right margins to space things out; you could remove those or replace with, say, a right-only margin on the first rectangle if you wanted to have it flush with the column text.

Hope this helps…

Comment: Hi William, thanks for that, sorry about the diagram, it's actually a screengrab from lynda.com. To clarify it's supposed to be 20px of padding on the left box (the 590px), 20 px margin between the two main boxes, and then 20px padding right on the rightmost box (350px). Then there's 10px of padding for the two 250px boxes.So I understand you get the percentage by dividing by the parent element, what I don't get is that the teacher says that to get the content width (250px) you divide it by the total parent width(590px) yet to calculate the inner paddings (10px around the 250px) you do so...

Comment: ...based on the parent's inner width (570px as opposed to the 590 total width).. So I just don't understand why you would use the 590 context for one and then the 570 for the other.